# How to differ regular and iframe requests through a service worker?

Tags: javascript, iframe, service-worker

- There's a page with an iframe (`http://localhost:8080`) and connected service worker that monitors all the `fetch` requests from both the page and the iframe.
- There're some internal page requests (loading favicon, internal scripts, etc.) and iframe requests (loading static resources for the page in the iframe).
- When iframe resources (like css) have absolute links - no problem, it's easy to differ local requests (start with `http://localhost:8080`) and iframe requests (start with external netloc).
- When iframe resources have non-absolute links, like `images/smth.jpg` - I can't differ internal and external requests because they all start with `http://localhost:8080`.

So, the question is: how to differ such requests? Maybe, there's a way to see the source element of the request (iframe)?

For now, the only solution I implemented is to move all the local resources to some `hard-unique-named` folder, and if the request doesn't start with it - it can be counted as an iframe request. Still, I hope there's a better solution :)

Comment: Possibly, it could be done by monitoring `clientId`, so need to catch some obviously local id, save it, and then compare with all other ones.

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution. You can catch all the `clientId`s after iframe `load` and than just filter all the main window requests based on `clientId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple enough, as it turned out. Firstly, you need to send a message to the service worker after its and iframe's activation (sending from the iframe):

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('iframe_worker.js').then(function (registration) {
            // Registration was successful
            console.log('Iframe Service Worker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
            // -> SEND MESSAGE TO GET CLIENT ID
            registration.active.postMessage({code: "get-client-id"});
        }, function (err) {
            // registration failed :(
            console.log('Service Worker registration failed: ', err);
        });
    });
}
```

Then, you need to process the message and iterate through `clientId`s, so you can save the main window and the iframe IDs as variables to use in filtering.

```
let windowClientId = '';
let iframeClientId = '';

addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data.code === 'get-client-id') {
        self.clients.matchAll().then(function (clients) {
            clients.forEach(function (client) {
                if (client.frameType === "top-level") {
                    windowClientId = client.id
                } else if (client.frameType === "nested") {
                    iframeClientId = client.id
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

After that, you can just filter and process requests as you want:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    // Don't process any requests if worker/iframe are not activated fully
    if (!windowClientId || !iframeClientId) {
        return;
    }
    // Don't process main window resources
    if (event.clientId === windowClientId) {
        return;
    }
    // do smth
})
```